# how to make a page with record displayed from database

Tags: forms

I am using a cutom module to display records from database.code below fetches all the record from database table but does not know how to display it on a page in my Drupal site (version 7):

---

```
function formModule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['form/formModule'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
    'title' => 'Form', //page title
    'description' => 'A form with a text field and Submit button.',
    'page callback' => 'formModule_intro', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form

    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'expanded' => TRUE,
  );

  $items['form/formModule/form1'] = array(
    'title' => 'Form One',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('formModule_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'weight' => 1,
  );

  $items['form/formModule/reviewOrder'] = array(
    'title' => 'Review Order',
    'page callback' => 'formModule_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'weight' => 2,
  );

  return $items;
}


function formModule_page() {
return array('#markup' => '<p>' . t('Review Order: The table below shows the TOTAL STOCK and TOTAL QUANTITY of product purchased.') . '</p>');

  $query = db_select('formmodule_order', 't'); // Using the TableSort Extender is what tells the
  $query->fields('t');
  $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

 $rows[] = array('data' => (array) $row);

  foreach ($result as $key => $row) { 
  $rows[$key] = array(); 

  foreach($row as $col) {
   $rows[$key][] = array('data' => $col); 

   } 
  }
drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($rows, true) . "</pre>");

}
```

---

iam using the following code to dispaly it on a page but no results:

---

```
$header = array(
    // The header gives the table the information it needs in order to make
    // the query calls for ordering. TableSort uses the field information
    // to know what database column to sort by.
    array('data' => t('S.No.'), 'field' => 't.S.No.'),
    array('data' => t('Product Name'), 'field' => 't.Product Name'),
    array('data' => t('Total Stock'), 'field' => 't.Total Stock'),
    array('data' => t('Total Purchasing'), 'field' => 't.Total Purchasing'),

  );
 drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($header, true) . "</pre>");**/
  $query = db_select('formmodule_order', 't'); // Using the TableSort Extender is what tells the

            // the query object that we are sorting.
  $query->fields('t');

//drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($query, true) . "</pre>");

 $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

// drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($result, true) . "</pre>");

  foreach ($result as $key => $row) { 
  $rows[$key] = array(); 
   foreach($row as $col) {
   $rows[$key][] = array('data' => $col); 
   } 
  }
drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($rows, true) . "</pre>");
  // build the table for the nice output.
  $build['formmodule_order'] = array(
    //'#theme' => 'table',
    //'#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
  );

 drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($build, true) . "</pre>");
  return $build;
```

---

what is wrong in the code?

Comment: Aashi, you still don't accept or upvote any of the answers to your questions. You should do this because it is a return to the others who help you. Otherwise, you may lose the helps from those in the future.

Comment: The fact you are not accepting answers could be interpreted as you are not trying to apply what suggested, or not listening to the given answers. The fact you don't even comment about not understanding the answers could lead to believe you don't even try to apply what suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because before anything has a chance to print you are already returning `#markup` from `formModule_page()`.
You might also want to use the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module's `dpm()` function for more cleaner and convenient debug messages and variable inspection.